# How to disable login window on Windows server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, administration

How to disable login window on Windows Serve 2003 startup?

Although there is no password required I still have to press OK or enter every time on login.

Thanks.

Comment: -1 for not using password on Windows Server. But if you're ok with that you might have better chance in getting an answer on superuser.com

Comment: server is on VM and it is annoying to login every time when I switch form host machine to virtual machine.

Comment: If its a VM, can you just save the state of the machine after login sequence and just resume from that point each time?

Comment: @Zach: Theoretically, yes. But there are times in testing when the act of restarting is important. I assume since it's a server OS being run in a VM, it's used as some sort of a testbed platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set Windows Server 2003 to automatically log on, perform the following steps:

1. Ensure that you are logged in with administrative privileges.
2. Open the Registry Editor (Start -> Run -> "regedt32.exe")
3. Navigate to the following subkey:

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
   ```
4. Double-click on the `DefaultUserName` entry, type your user name, and click OK. (If relevant for your network configuration, make sure that you set the `DefaultDomain` entry as well.)
5. Double-click on the `DefaultPassword` entry, type your password, and click OK. (If the `DefaultPassword` value does not exist, you need to create it in order for this to work.)
6. Add a new `REG_SZ` value (Edit -> New -> String Value).
7. Type `AutoAdminLogon` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
8. Double-click on the `AutoAdminLogon` value that you just added.
9. In the "Edit String" dialog box, type `1` and click OK.
10. Quit the Registry Editor.
11. Restart your computer. You should now be logged on automatically to the account that you specified.

If for whatever reason you need to bypass this automatic log-on and log in as a different user, you can hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as you log off.